# Error in if: argument is of length zero: encountered in a shiny app after trying to refer to an reactive element twice

Tags: r, shiny

I'm completely new to R and shiny apps and couldn't find a solution for this specific problem:
I tried to realize a shiny app that allows users to upload their own data file and do further analysis with the columns of the specific data file. Computing Cohen's D and the t-test works just fine. Only the effect size of Cohen's D seems to be problematic.
I really don't get what I'm doing wrong/missing. Maybe it's because I'm referring to the reactive element "linking" twice or in the wrong order, I really don't know.

The entire code:

```
library(shiny)
library(effectsize)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    div(id = "myapp",
        h2("Upload my own data"),
        fileInput("example", "",
                  accept= c("csv")),
        actionButton("load", "Upload data"), 
        conditionalPanel(                    
          condition = "input.load >= '1'",   
          uiOutput("var1"),                 
          uiOutput("var2")),
        h2("Compute Cohen's D"),
        actionButton("selectD", "Show"),
        conditionalPanel(                    
          condition = "input.selectD >= '1'",   
          uiOutput("cohensd")),
        h2("Effect Size Cohen's D"),
        actionButton("selectDEf", "Show"),
        conditionalPanel(                    
          condition = "input.selectDEf >= '1'",   
          uiOutput("cohensdEsize")),
        h2("Compute t-test"), 
        actionButton("select", "Show"),
        conditionalPanel(                    
          condition = "input.select >= '1'",    
          uiOutput("t.test"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("cohen")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    values <- reactiveValues()
    dataInput <- reactive({
      data <- read.csv(input$example$datapath)
    }
    )
    output$var1 <- renderUI({    # remember variable 1? here it is how we extract it
      nam <- colnames(values$data) # from the data set
      selectInput("var1", label = "Select group 1:", # create the input
                  choices = c(nam), multiple = FALSE,
                  selected = nam[1])
    })
    
    output$var2 <- renderUI({
      nam2 <- colnames(values$data) # create the input for variable 2
      selectInput("var2", label = "Select group 2:",
                  choices = c(nam2), multiple = FALSE,
                  selected = nam2[1])
    })
    observeEvent(input$load, {
      values$data <- data.frame(dataInput())
    })
    output$t.test = renderPrint({
      t <- t.test(values$data[,input$var1],values$data[,input$var2])
      cat("t-statistic:", t$statistic, "| degrees of freedom:", t$parameter, "| p-value:", t$p.value)
    })
    linking <- reactive({
      mean1 <- mean(values$data[,input$var1])
      mean2 <- mean(values$data[,input$var2])
      sd1 <- sd(values$data[,input$var1])
      sd2 <- sd(values$data[,input$var2])
      n1 <- length(values$data[,input$var1])
      n2 <- length(values$data[,input$var2])
      cat((mean1 - mean2)/
            (sqrt((n1 - 1)*(sd1^2) + (n2 - 1)*(sd2*2)) / (n1 + n2 - 2)))
    })
    output$cohensd = renderPrint(linking())
    output$cohensdEsize = renderPrint({linking()*4
    })
  })
```

The error: Error in if: argument is of length zero
I don't get why linking() should be empty
If somebody could help me, I would be very thankful!

Comment: the result of `linking()` is `cat` which returns `NULL`

Comment: To be clear: remove `cat` (and keep all of its contents). The block needs to return a value, and `cat` does not do that (ever).